# Troubleshooting a ZCD TRIAC circuit

Tags: opto-isolator, triac, code, zero-crossing

Can someone see what's wrong here? My 50 W LED light doesn't shine.

[image: Physical connection-board]

[image: Snubber-circuit]

Here is my code from the Arduino IDE:

```
const int AC_LOAD_PIN = 2;        // Output to Opto Triac pin
const int ZERO_CROSS_PIN = 3;     // Pin connected to the zero-crossing detector
const int MIN_DIMMING = 5;        // Minimum dimming level
const int MAX_DIMMING = 128;      // Maximum dimming level (0-128), 0 = ON, 128 = OFF
const int TRIAC_DELAY = 10;       // Triac on propagation delay in microseconds (for 60Hz use 8.33)

volatile int dimming = MIN_DIMMING; // Initialize dimming level to the minimum value
const unsigned long dimmingDuration = 60000; // Dimming duration in milliseconds (1 minute)
const unsigned long loopDelay = dimmingDuration / (MAX_DIMMING - MIN_DIMMING);
volatile bool reachedMaxBrightness = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(AC_LOAD_PIN, OUTPUT);    // Set AC Load pin as output
  pinMode(ZERO_CROSS_PIN, INPUT);  // Set zero-crossing detector pin as input
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(ZERO_CROSS_PIN), zeroCrossingInterrupt, RISING); // Attach interrupt for zero crossing
}

// Interrupt function for zero crossing, takes no parameters and returns nothing
void zeroCrossingInterrupt() {
  if (!reachedMaxBrightness) {
    int dimTime = calculateDimTime();
    delayMicroseconds(dimTime);      // Wait until firing the TRIAC
    digitalWrite(AC_LOAD_PIN, HIGH); // Fire the TRIAC
    delayMicroseconds(TRIAC_DELAY);  // TRIAC on propagation delay
    digitalWrite(AC_LOAD_PIN, LOW);  // No longer trigger the TRIAC (the next zero crossing will switch it off)
  }
}

// Function to calculate the dim time based on dimming level
int calculateDimTime() {
  // Firing angle calculation: 1 full 50Hz wave = 1/50 = 20ms
  // Every zero crossing: (50Hz) -> 10ms (1/2 cycle)
  // For 60Hz => 8.33ms (10,000/120)
  // 10ms = 10,000us
  // (10,000us - 10us) / 128 = 75 (approx.) For 60Hz => 65

  return (82 * dimming); // For 60Hz => 65
}

void loop() {
for (int i = MIN_DIMMING; i <= MAX_DIMMING; i++) {
  dimming = i;
  delay(loopDelay);
}
for (int i = MAX_DIMMING; i >= MIN_DIMMING; i--) {
  dimming = i;
  delay(loopDelay);
}
  reachedMaxBrightness = true; // Set the flag to indicate maximum brightness is reached
  while (true); // Keep the loop running indefinitely to maintain full brightness
}
```

Here I have connected my oscilloscope to pin 3 on the Arduino. Or pin 5 on 4N25. Scope probe ground is connected to GND on Uno R3.

[image: Pin 3 on Arduino Uno R3]

Zoom:
[image: Zoom Pin 3]

Here I have connected my oscilloscope to Pin 2 on Uno R3. Scope probe ground is connected to GND on Uno R3. This is before the 220 Ω resistor.

[image: Pin 2 on Arduino Uno R3]

Zoom:
[image: Zoom Pin 2]

Here I have connected my oscilloscope to 1 Anode on MOC3020M. The voltage drops. Scope probe ground is connected to GND on Uno R3.

[image]

Zoom:
[image: Zoom 1 Anode MOC3020M]

**UPDATE 22.03.21**

I have made a readable wiring diagram using CircuitLab. I have also used ChatGPT to modify my code, but the circuit behaves the same way, so I can eliminate a software issue. I have updated the software in this post.

[image: Wiring-diagram]

Here is a picture of my oscilloscope with all three channels active at the same time:

[image: Scopx3]

When I upload the software I have a multimeter connected to L and N on the LED. The LED start flashing immediately between approximatley 100-185 VAC.

**UPDATE 23.03.21**

Thanks for all help and answers, I have updated my circuit and schematic with the following changes:

- R4 is replaced with a 180 Ω resistor
- R5 is replaced with a 680 Ω resistor
- Added a snubber circuit for the TRIAC with 0.1 μF capacitator and a 2,4 kΩ resistor

[image: Updated schematic-drawing]

So now my circuit is a little bit better: when I upload the code I measure approx. 140 VAC out to the LED, it flashes a lot. See picture below captured at startup:

[image: startup]

So I obviously still have a challenge with my circut. The ZCD part looks good to me, so I'm struggeling with this. Why is the TRIAC trigger signal (blue) from pin 2 so unstable?

Here is a picture at approx. 215 VAC:
A
[image: end]

So when i zoom in on the the pulses i can see that something is happening with the yellow ZCD-pulse between the 5V-peaks. Whatever it is that seems to be triggering the blue triac signal?

[image: zoom noise]

Here i have zoomed in at the noise? bewteen the 5V ZCD-pulses that seems to trigger the blue triac signal:

[image: extra zoom noise]

**WORKING!!**

I changed the 4N25 to EL817, and the circuit works fine! I tried several other 4N25 but then it is only flashing.

[image: Wokring]

Comment: What’s wrong? How is is supposed to work and what is observed? Please post oscillograms.

Comment: Are you really running 230VAC through a solderless breadboard?

Comment: Your schematic is jumbled and messy and badly drawn (given that the lined paper lines are about the same thickness and colour as your connections).

Comment: winny: I have updated the post!
JRE: Yes, why not?
Andy aka: Yes, im sorry. Its the only paper i got, wont help to turn it 180 degress either..

Comment: _"ocsiolloscope to Anode 1 on MOC3020. Only 1.8V? Its strange beacuse when i disconnect the wire from Anode 1 i measure 5V"_ No wonder. You are short circuiting the 5 V output from your MCU into an LED without current limiting. I would recommend you start with the basics before attempting anything mains connected, especially on a breadboard. Buy a ready made dimmer module? Correction: 20 VAC is safe but may introduce other issues such as holding current for a TRIAC.

Comment: @Mickolini:  Because solderless breadboards are generally only rated to low voltages ([SELV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra-low_voltage).)  There are exceptions, but in general they are not intended for use with line voltage.  Then there's the whole safety aspect - you've got bare wires all over the place carrying 230VAC.

Comment: @JRE - Yes, the Triac is not insulated. If he touch the cooling plate of the triac, then bad things could happen. If he is touching the shielding of the Arduino and the triac, then the 30mA fuse will drop. (hopefully) At least he should use shrink tube over the triac to reduce the risk.

Comment: It looks like you have a USB cable attached to the Arduino, which in turn has connections to your mains. It may be "safe" due to the 100k resistors to each side of mains (current limited to about 2 mA), but it would be best to disconnect the USB before powering your circuit. Also, show where your scope probe ground is connected when you show waveforms.

Comment: @winny You are right! I have added a 220ohm resistor, but it still goes from 5V to 1,3V? See the updated schematic in the post.

Comment: @JRE The breadboard are rated for 300V / 3-5A.

Comment: @PStechPaul Thanks for the tips. The scope probe groud was connected to GND on the microcontroller for both pictures.

Comment: Strange. How do you power your MCU?

Comment: @winny USB-cable from my PC

Comment: Something is not right. You sure it's 220 ohm? Can you capture Vcc and pin 2 on an oscilloscope?

Comment: @winny I have updated the post with proper scope-pictures. Yes the resistance is 220Ohm (216.8Ohm actually).

Comment: How long are you pulses? Can you zoom in on one?

Comment: @winny I have updated the post! :)

Comment: Take a look at the datasheet. I interpret it as you need 100 us pulse width at 15 mA. You pulse may be too short.

Comment: @winny Thanks for your help. I have read the datasheet multiple times. 5V/220Ohm=22,7mA and I_f is max 60mA. I cant find anything about required pulse width?

Comment: Page 5, figure 5. Try increasing your on-time of your trigger pulse. If that solves your issue, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: @winny I have tried increasing my on-time, everything from 10 to 1000 us. I can measure it on my scope and see that it is correct. After i corrected the mistake on Triac A1/A2 my light flashes, and the intesity of the flash changen with the pulsewidth..

Comment: @Mickolini - The MOC3020 need 15-30mA to trigger. Your calculation is wrong. There is a IR-LED inside of the MOC    Best case scenario: R=(5V - 1.15V) / 0.015A = 256 Ohm | Worst case scenario: R=(5V - 1.5V) / 0.030A = 116 Ohm | Data source: https://docs.rs-online.com/71ee/0900766b814e88cc.pdf  You have to try with the low value and then increase the value till the MOC does not do his job any more.  The MOC3023 only need less than 5mA.

Comment: What are the three traces shown? I'm guessing orange is the AC line and blue is the trigger pulse. What is the yellow trace? Also, the signals are very noisy. AND the trigger pulses are not synchronized with line frequency.

Comment: @winny A 220Ohm resistor should be good between 17,5 to 15,9 mA? Anyway, i changed it to 180Ohm.

Comment: @PStechPaul I have uploaded a new picture that should be easier to see. All the brown and blue wires are AC-line L/N. I agree,  "trigger pulses are not synchronized with line frequency" must be the problem, but i cant fint the reason..

Comment: Again, please zoom in your oscillograms in time a bit. If your pulse width is ~1 pixel wide, depending on scope settings, it may not show.

Comment: @winny Again, im sorry, very good idea! Please see the updated pictrures, seems to be some noise causing the triac pulse to trigger at the wrong point

Answer (score 1):

The MOC circuit is not right.
Use this circuit for the MOC instead and be very carefully with the voltage.
[image]
Source: https://www.silicon-ark.co.uk/datasheets/moc3020-datasheet-motorola.pdf

Your oscilloscope is able to make pictures and store it on a USB-drive.

The MOC3063 is able to make this zero crossing by himself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will defenetly check out MOC3063. But i cant see why my MOC-circut is not right? I have connenced the same way exept for the extra resistors and capacitators.

Comment: @Mickolini you have the MOC3020 connected between A1 and gate. It should go to A2 as shown above, and should have current limiting resistors.

Comment: @PStechPaul Good observation! I have switched connection on A1 and A2 so now it goes from A1 to the LED and from A2 phase L. I also have a current limiting resistor of 200kOhm between phase L and 6 on MOC3020. After this my LED flashes, good news! But i still can dim the light smooth, i have tried several codes. I can only change the intensity of the flashing..

Comment: @PStechPaul - What type of LED are you using? Some LEDs are not dimmable by design.

Comment: @Mickolini The current limiting resistor should be around 500 to 800 ohms. Please update your schematic with the changes suggested. Preferably using CircuitLab. Also, how much current does your lamp load draw? There is minimum holding current for your triac.

Comment: @PStechPaul Could you please explain why they should be so low? I have updated my schematic using CircuitLab. My LED-lamp is 50W so that would be approx 0,22A. I have also tried with 9 lamps and that would be about 450W.

Comment: The Fairchild data sheet shows 180 ohms in series with the gate, for a resistive load. And for a sensitive gate triac, a 2.4k resistor and 100 nF capacitor are added, as @MikroPower shows above. Your LED module is probably capacitve, which changes the current vs voltage phase angle.

Comment: @PStechPaul Can you send a link to the Fairchild data sheet? I have added your suggestions to the circuit, but it dosent solve the problem..

Comment: Here you go: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/MOC3023M-1118119.pdf

Comment: I see you got it working with the EL817, which probably has a higher transfer ratio than the 4N25. You might want to specify the EL817D version, which has a CTR of 300-600. The LED emitter sees only 1-2 mA peak and much less near zero crossing. The 4N25 has a CTR of just 20-50.  https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/143/EL817-1663334.pdf